# Return behaviour in recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return

I can't quite wrap my mind around the behaviours of the `return` statements in the below recursive function. Having returns within both the `if` and `else` statements, I get the `int` value returned as desired, however with either removed the functions return `None`.

I expected to only require a return statement within `else` as any iteration running through the `if` statement would recursively initiate the calculate function until it bypasses `if`

```
def solution(n, b):
    results = {}
    j = 0
    k = len(str(n))
    return calculate(n, b, j, k, results)


def calculate(n, b, j, k, results):
    i = ''
    x = ''.join(sorted([i for i in str(n)])[::-1])
    y = x[::-1]
    z = int(x, b) - int(y, b)
    while z:
        i = int(str(z % b) + str(i))
        z = z // b
    i = '0'*(k-len(str(i))) + str(i)
    if i not in results.values():
        results[j] = i
        j += 1
        s = calculate(i, b, j, k, results)
        return s #commenting this line causes code to return None
    else: #commenting else statement causes code to return None
        return len(results.keys()) - list(results.keys())[list(results.values()).index(i)]


print(solution('210022', 3))
```

Comment: besides commenting out `else` statement, you need to decrease indent of its return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all functions, recursive or otherwise, that end their execution return a value, if no explicit value is provided with a `return` statement then a `None` is delivered to its caller by default.

Take for example this sample function:

```
>>> def test(x):
        if x:
            s="if case"
        else:
            return "else case"

    
>>> print(test(True))
None
>>> print(test(False))
else case
>>>
```

Here in the first case you enter the "if case" execute all the block of code there, because no return statement is present, you leave the if-else block of code and proceed to the next but in this case there is no more piece of code to run so the function end its execution returning None by default.

In the second case you enter the "else case" but here you find a `return` statement which tell the function to end its execution at this point and deliver that value to its caller.

You need to be explicit with what value you want out of the function, and just because the function end up calling itself doesn't mean that the function will magically know that one this is a recursive function (that is just but one programming technique) or two that you want the result from the other branch of some if-else block somewhere in your code somewhere in some functions calls chain.

A recursive call is treated not different that calling any other function, it just so happens that the function is calling itself, so if you do nothing with the result you get from some function call inside your function, you naturally get nothing out of it

Here is second example with the factorial function

```
>>> def fact_bad(n,r=1):
        if n<=1:
            return r
        else:
            ans=fact_bad(n-1,n*r)

        
>>> def fact_good(n,r=1):
        if n<=1:
            return r
        else:
            ans=fact_good(n-1,n*r)
            return ans

    
>>> fact_bad(5) #you get nothing here because you do nothing with your recursive call inside
>>> fact_good(5) #you get your result as desire because because you do something with your recursive call inside, in this case that is just returning it
120
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for this write up. Your simplified examples helped me click that each recursive function call needs to 'return' and complete the 'if' statement it was called from and each 'return' brings the final else statement 'return' from the deepest function call.